# Convert text to time value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
29.08.2018 11:52:16.9040000
29.08.2018 11:52:18.2880000
```

I need to convert in time format, and then calculate difference.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/timevalue-function-0b615c12-33d8-4431-bf3d-f3eb6d186645 then just subtract them and format result as time.

Comment: Maybe you use some national datetime format? try to replace a decimal point in seconds value with a comma and then format cells as datetime. To calculate the difference simply substract values (and multiply by a proper value to obtain the result in units you need).

Comment: I tried all that not helping

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes the **date part is the same** for both values.

With data in **A1** and **A2**, in **B1** and **B2**enter:

```
=--MID(A1,12,9999)
=--MID(A2,12,9999)
```

This discards the date part and gives the time part including milliseconds. In **B3** enter:

```
=B2-B1
```

Finally format the cells in column **B** as *hh:mm:ss.000*

[image]

Comment: Finally format the cells in column B as hh:mm:ss.000 . I can not format like this

Comment: @ivica Then pick your own formatting

Comment: If you set `B1` to `=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,7,4)&"-"&MID(A1,4,2)&"-"&LEFT(A1,2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,16))` and `B2` similarly, then you can handle times that transcend days, but you need the format `[hh]:mm:ss.000` to show the total hours difference. Alternatively, you can show the total difference in seconds with general format in `B3` set to `=86400*(B2-B1)`. Note that for the test data this shows `1.384000364` on Excel2007, showing the lack of accuracy in time values, which are held as fractions of a day. The test data imply a resolution of 0.1 microseconds, which Excel won't handle accurately.